# How to enable Blazor hot reload

Tags: blazor-server-side

Having watched Dan Roth's Blazor demo (15 Jan 2020), code changes to a razor file were refreshed to the browser without the stop|build|run cycle.  On my VS2019 (latest) I don't get that hot reload.  This is a new Blazor SS project from the standard template.  Is there a property required to be set to enable it?

I tried 
dotnet run watch 
but no difference

Comment: Never seen this hot reload, what is that video?

Comment: It's in the .Net Conf videos, Welcome to Blazor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlngrOF6RPw&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oWlP1Qpzg7Dwzxr298ewdUQ

Comment: At what time? Do not see it.

Comment: It's at around 31mins 9 seconds

Comment: Yes, but he did not even build the app and plainly he is not even debugging or running the project, it seems just a trick in the video to me.

Comment: Using dotnet watch run from the project root in a command window gets you pretty close to this. True hot reload is coming in .Net 5 which I think is in preview release now if you're feeling adventurous. ;)

Comment: If you run a Blazor app without debugging forom Visual Studio you could after starting up the app with Ctrl+F5 hit F6 to rebuild (these are the default key bindings to these commands if you have not overriden those) and then refresh the browser window with F5. Sadly, not a hot reload, but you at least dont have to startup again the entire app - only recompile it and the web assemblies / web assembly should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: 12-04-2021**

Initial .NET Hot Reload support
Early support for .NET Hot Reload is now available for ASP.NET Core & Blazor projects using dotnet watch. .NET Hot Reload applies code changes to your running app without restarting it and without losing app state.

To try out hot reload with an existing ASP.NET Core project based on .NET 6, add the "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore" property to your launch profile in launchSettings.json. For Blazor WebAssembly projects, use the "blazorwasm" hot reload profile.

Run the project using dotnet watch. The output should indicate that hot reload is enabled:

watch : Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload. Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
If at any point you want to force the app to rebuild and restart, you can do so by entering Ctrl+R at the console.

You can now start making edits to your code. As you save code changes, applicable changes are automatically hot reloaded into the running app almost instantaneously. Any app state in the running app is preserved.

**OLD ANSWER**

This will come in .NET 6 hopefully. But at the time of writing this is still not working yet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it

Comment: This has now been released in [.NET 6.0 Preview 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/)

Comment: Hot reload does NOT work on blazor wasm with .net 6.0.100. I have tested this extensively using VSCode and VS 2022. No refresh happens. I am testing on a unmodified new blazor template.

Comment: Are you getting: "No hot reload changes to apply" in the command line? then try: dotnet watch --project ./
more info here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38036#issuecomment-950749664

Comment: Adding "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore" solved it for me (in .net 8.0 Server project)